# Prompt to copy CSR to local folder IFF one is generated in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that does all the configuration for new VMs, one of the roles is responsible for setting up PKI keys.  As part of this it generates a private key and a certificate sign request if it doesn't already exist.  Our company has a separate, sadly manual, process for submitting a CSR to get it signed that will have to be done after the CSR is generated.

I want to create a handler that only runs if at least one new CSR was generated.  In that handler I want to have a prompt that asks if the user wants to copy back any new CSR to a local folder, so all the new CSR can be consolidated to make it easier to submit the requests.  My problem is I can't seem to figure out how to put a prompt inside of a handler that will prompt only if new CSR are created.

Comment: Something I do not get in the process: is the Ansible playbook generating the CSR? If yes, then indeed the changed status on the task generating the CSR can help you "conditionally" have the handler run and so it would be a good idea for your use case. Otherwise, I don't see the use of a handler, and you should just have a conditional task based on your user input.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Currently a role generates the CSR, not the playbook.  though if I had to move the CSR generation into the playbook instead I wouldn't be too upset, it's barely enough happening to warrant a role.  My problem was more that I don't know how to fit a prompt in a handler, it seems like prompts have to run at play book level without any conditional logic?